# How can I make a list of all applications running in Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows

I want to create a list of all applications running in Windows using Java. The list should consist of applications only and not all processes. How can I do this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you know how to distinguish an "application" from any other process, you can analyze the String line.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Make the question explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the tasklist as normal, then insert the name of the process (without .exe) into this command:

`PowerShell Get-Process <name> ^| Format-List Path`

eg. `PowerShell Get-Process chrome ^| Format-List Path`

If the output contains "Program Files" its most likely an application, else it probably isn't. This requires PowerShell of course^^